# Ubuntu desktop logs me into the Activities overview menu and I can't click anywhere nor do anything [Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS]

Tags: gnome, 22.04, desktop-environments

When I turn on my PC, it automatically boots to my desktop with a frozen view of the **activities overview** menu, just like this:

[image: 1]

Then I can't click anywhere or anything, and I end up restarting the PC (a few times) until it suddenly works. Sometimes I can hit `Alt+F2` and press `R` to reload the desktop, and that fixes everything. But other times pressing that key (or any other) does nothing and I end up rebooting anyway. Quite annoying...

Comment: You will have to provide detail: in a default system, no applications are open when a system restarts. Perhaps instead, you are restarting your computer from the suspended state? Use "edit"  to add the clarification to your answer. Also indicate whether you use Wayland or Xorg, and provide information on your graphics card and hardware.

Comment: Wayland or X11?

Answer (score 0):

I've just switched from `X11` to `Wayland`, seems it doesn't happpen anymore.
Thanks everyone!!